# Android studio IDE Layout changed after Upgrade to 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

How to change back the layout of the IDE (Android studio) to normal position? As you can see the make project button, run program button and etc are on the far right. This happend after I updated the IDE to 0.5.5. Please help me. Thank you. Shift-F12 don't work.

[image]

The Picture below should be the normal one i think.
[image]

Comment: Your question mentioned Android Studio 1.5 which has just been released. It's shocking that you asked it over a year ago. I see that your title has a typo. It's version **0.5.5**. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hidden the toolbar. Use **View menu > Toolbar** to restore it.